# Coefficient matching method for SDEs

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

I am using the book by M.Steele, Stochastic calculus and financial applications and came across the following solution method in chapter 9. The method is called coefficient matching and starts like:

$$dX(t) = \mu X(t)dt + \sigma X(t)dB(t) \quad \text{with } X(0) = x_0>0$$

where $B(t)$ is a Brownian motion and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are constants. Deriving $dX(t)$ usign Ito's lemma and assuming $X(t) = f(t,B(t))$ yields

$$dX(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dB(t) +\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)dt$$

Now matching the coefficients yields

$$\mu f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$$

$$\sigma f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

Now one can find the function $f(x,t)$ using the second equation which yields

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(t,x) & = e^{\sigma x + g(t)}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Using this $f(t,x)$ for the first equation

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
g^{\prime}(t) &= \mu  -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

As the next step the book says that now we get

$$f(t,x) = x_0e^{\sigma x +(\mu  -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t}$$

and hence

$$X(t) = x_0e^{(\mu  -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t +\sigma dB(t)}$$

Could someone explain how to get the last two equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have derived that $g'(t) = \mu -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2$. Integrating both sides yields 
$$g(t) = \left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t+C,$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. We can then write
\begin{align}
f(t,x) &= \exp\{\sigma x+g(t)\} \\
&= \exp\left\{\sigma x + \left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t+C \right\}  \\
&= \exp\{C\} \exp\left\{\sigma x + \left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t \right\} \quad (*) .
\end{align}
The expression for $X(t)$ follows immediately by the definition
$$X(t) = f(t,B(t)).$$
(Substitute $B(t)$ for $x$ in $(*)$). The value of $C$ can be determined by the initial condition. Since $X(0) = x_0$, this implies
$$C = \ln(x_0).$$